# Why some tables are not displaying appropriate in Android App? though we have also used responsive table

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, web-applications, android-listview

we are displaying table data from json response. responsive table we used for displaying table.

here is my sample code for responsive table

```
<table class = "responsivetable" width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Scripted Testing</td>
    <td>Exploratory Testing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Directed from requirements</td>
    <td>Directed from requirements and exploring during testing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Determination of test cases well in advance</td>
    <td>Determination of test cases during testing</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And style for responsive table

```
<style>
   /* General Table Style */
   table.responsivetable {
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   .responsivetable tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: #eee;
   }
   .responsivetable thead tr td {
   background-color: #333;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   }
   .responsivetable td, .responsivetable th {
   padding: 6px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   text-align: left;
   }

      /* Make Table Responsive --- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
.responsivetable table, .responsivetable thead, .responsivetable th, .responsivetable tr, .responsivetable td {
display: block;
}
/* Hide table headers (but not display:none, for accessibility) */
.responsivetable thead tr {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}
.responsivetable tr {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.responsivetable td {
/* Behave like a row */
border: none;
padding-left: 50%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
position: relative;
}
.responsivetable td:before {
/* Now, like a table header */
position: absolute;
/* Top / left values mimic padding */
top: 6px; left: 6px;
width: 45%;
padding-right: 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
/* -- LABEL THE DATA -- */
.responsivetable td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Scripted Testing"; }
.responsivetable td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Exploratory Testing"; }
}/* End responsive query */
</style>
```

Also when i am using simple table and not responsive one then also some tables not displaying appropriate.

Here you can check what is actual look of table - http://screencast.com/t/Z6mG7af3de63

now when i am trying to display this table in android app it is look like this - http://screencast.com/t/pABJrUKDhh.

So can you guys suggest me what is the actual problem by which this can be happend.

please help.